# Concatenate 2 letters with preg_replace and regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of company names to process, and send to various places after formatting.
My current issue is the following :

**Example lines**

**J C** PENNEY CO INC

DOLLAR TREE INC

**C H** ROBINSON WORLDWIDE INC

GOOGLE INC

I would like to concatenate the single letters J C , and C H into JC and CH, so the final result reads :

**JC** PENNEY CO INC

DOLLAR TREE INC

**CH** ROBINSON WORLDWIDE INC

GOOGLE INC

This should happen only at the beginning of the word. I have no problem finding the pattern, with `/^\w\s\w\s/`, but how can I remove the space in the middle? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [capturing group](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).

For example:

```
$name = 'J C PENNEY CO INC';
$name = preg_replace('/^(\w)\s(\w\s)/', '$1$2', $name);
var_dump($name);
```

Comment: Man, that answer rocks, I just understood the group thing as well as sorting out my issue. It always eluded me... Thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.